# Scala Anorm select 2 values using column resolution

Tags: scala, anorm

According to documentation (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Anorm), I can do the following to retrieve values from 2 columns:

```
val res: (String, Int) = SQL"SELECT text, count AS i".map(row =>
  row[String]("text") -> row[Int]("i")
)
```

This does not compile...

Causes this:

> Expression of type SimpleSql[(String, Int)] doesn't conform to expected type (String, Int)

I'm just looking for a single method of doing this (for anorm 2.5+). I was using regular parsers but am looking for this more concise way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is not complete: to get a single result as such tuple, the `.single` combinator must be used.

```
val res: (String, Int) = SQL"SELECT text, count AS i".map(row =>
  row[String]("text") -> row[Int]("i")
).single
```

> Using Anorm flatteners is easier for tuple result: [see examples](https://github.com/playframework/anorm/blob/master/core/src/test/scala/anorm/TupleFlattenerSpec.scala)

Comment: The `.single` combinator seems to have been deprecated. Is there an alternative?

Comment: I don't know where you see that. It's not deprecated at all.